# jQuery how can you verify date formatted mm/dd/yyyy is not greater than current date today

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I verify in jQuery that a date entered on a input text box or value in html such as mm/dd/yyyy is not greater than todays date.  Example would be "5/5/2011" would pass as true b/c its not greater than today "6/17/2011", but "5/5/3011" would be greater than today and should return false. Is there a simple function that can return true or false if a date in form "mm/dd/yyyy" is greater than todays date in javascript or jQuery?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just convert to a `Date` object and compare your date value to `Date.now` - for example:

```
alert( Date.parse("3/1/2012") > Date.now())
```

You do not actually need to use jQuery for this at all, pure JavaScript is good enough. Please have a look at the docs for Javascript [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

convert to javascript Date objects to compare.

Answer (score 2):

```
var d = new Date("5/5/2011")
var d2 = new Date()

var b = d < d2 // << true...
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, you need to be sure that dates have a universal format. 10/1/2011 is in the future in the US (October 1st, 2011) but in the past in the UK (10th January 2011). If that's satisfied, the below will work just fine:

```
function greaterThanToday(datestring) {
  var today = new Date();
  var date = new Date(datestring);
  return (date > today);
}

alert("5/5/2011: " + greaterThanToday("5/5/2011"));
alert("5/5/3011: " + greaterThanToday("5/5/3011"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't even need jQuery, just Date objects.

```
Date.parse("6/17/2011") > Date.parse("5/5/3011")
```